# Using keyed stream keys for preloading

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to do preloading of some data from remote data source depending on the key available for the current operator. Keyed process function has [ctx.getCurrentKey](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/KeyedProcessFunction.Context.html#getCurrentKey--) but we cannot use it in open method.

How can I achieve fetching this data only once.

```java
// main

DataStream<EnrichedSensorMeasurement> enrichedMeasurements = measurements
            .keyBy(elem -> elem.getCustomerId())
            .flatMap(new EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement())
            .uid("EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement")
            .name("Enrichment With Preloading For SensorMeasurement");

// function
public class EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement
    extends RichFlatMapFunction<SensorMeasurement, EnrichedSensorMeasurement> {
```

Trying to use a constructor does not work due flatMap expecting specific type:

```java
DataStream<EnrichedSensorMeasurement> enrichedMeasurements = measurements
            .keyBy(elem -> elem.getCustomerId())
            .flatMap(elem -> new EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement(elem.getCustomerId()))
            .uid("EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement")
            .name("Enrichment With Preloading For SensorMeasurement");
```

Is it possible to make a key specific operation on an operator only once (during setup) instead of processElement which is called for every element? Which APIs do flink provide for such use cases?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJS18iKLUIY and the accompanying GitHub repo (https://github.com/knaufk/enrichments-with-flink) are a good resource on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding FlatMap Typing

You mentioned an issue regarding the specific type expectation when trying to use your keyed flat map. You will need to ensure that the the types defined in your `EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement` align with the incoming stream (`measurements`). You may want to consider posting more of the function itself as well as indicating the types for your incoming stream to avoid a mismatch.

Additionally, Flink's mapping functions `map` and `flatMap` both accept a secondary operator that is used to handle type information, which could be relevant here and can be necessary:

```
.map(
  EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement(), 
  TypeInformation.of(EnrichedSensorMeasurement::class)
)
```

```
.flatMap(
  EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement(), 
  TypeInformation.of(EnrichedSensorMeasurement::class)
)
```

#### Regarding Preloading / Bootstrapping

You can accomplish this type of preloading using the [State Processor API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/libs/state_processor_api/) which allows you to essentially bootstrap savepoints for specific operators (based on their uids). This can be extremely useful if you have a large set of keys that might be slow to ingest *while* ingesting from other sources that would use it.

```
// Define your savepoint
val savepoint =  SavepointWriter.newSavepoint(DefaultConstants.MAX_PARALLELISM)   

// Read from your source (you'll ideally want to do this in a batch way to ensure that 
// all of your records are read/available)
val measurementEnrichmentStream = streamEnv
    .fromSource(yourMeasuresSource)
    .flatMap(EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement())

val transformation = OperatorTransformation
    .bootstrapWith(measurementEnrichmentStream)
    .keyBy(element -> element.getCustomerId())
    .transform(EnrichmentPreloadingBootstrap())

// Write your savepoint (uid should correspond to your respective
savepointWriter
    .withOperator("EnrichmentWithPreloadingForSensorMeasurement", transformation)
    .write(yourSavepointPath)
```

The bootstrap function would handle associating your keys to the expected state so that you don't have the overhead of creating these/keying them (for each of your distinct keys) while the job is running:

```
class EnrichedSensorMeasurementBootstrap(): KeyedStateBootstrapFunction<String, EnrichedSensorMeasurement>() {
    private lateinit var yourState: ValueState<EnrichedSensorMeasurement>

    override fun open(parameters: Configuration) {
        yourState = this.runtimeContext.getState(StateDescriptors.yourStateDescriptor)
    }

    override fun processElement(measurement: EnrichedSensorMeasurement, context: Context) {
        yourState.update(measurement)
    }
}
```